# Getting file size in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm downloading (from server to client) a file using a WebClient object:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.OpenReadCompleted += Load_TransferCompleted;
wc.OpenReadAsync(uriAddress, Filename);
```

I would like to know the file size *before* starting the download operation. Is there a way to do this in SL4?

thanks for your help.

Gilad.

Comment: It might help if we knew why you want to know the size before download?

Comment: I have multiple files (lets say 10) that are downloaded one after the other. I would like to show a progress bar and estimate the complete (for all the files) download operation duration. The files aren't the same size.

Comment: By how much to the sizes of the files vary?  Why not show progress as the number of files downloaded so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some air code for you to play with (I haven't tested it myself)

```
 WebRequest req = WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(yourUri);
 req.Method = "HEAD";
 req.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
 {
     WebResponse resp = req.EndGetResponse(ar);
     int length = resp.ContentLength;

     // Do stuff with length
 }, null);
```

By using the `ClientHttp` stack you can use "HEAD" request which will return the same set of headers as a "GET" but not the actual entity body.

There is at least one thing to look out for though, none of the existing cookies for the uri will be sent in the request.  If the response is sensitive to cookies (for example because it needs a session id) then things will get a whole lot more complicated.

Comment: This code throws security error at     WebResponse resp = req.EndGetResponse(ar);
. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see to make this possible is by publishing the size. It could be coded but also obtainable through a web service.

Comment: I was afraid of this, a Webservice isn't an option and manually adding the file size as a parameter is quite a hassle in the project.

Comment: In a way it is a good thing that server side things are not (easily) available for clients. Could you add the size to the page on which the silverlight app is hosted? It could even be a hidden input. In Silverlight you could use the HTML bridge to get to the hiddeninput and read the value. It is an awful hack but can be done.

Comment: I'm already adding the size to the HTML page. The problem with this is that I have to manually update the size each time the files are changed. I was thinking of a more effortless solution.

Comment: Make the Html page an ASPX page so it has some logic that is run on the server. The logic could read the size of the file.